# How to configure load-time weaving with AspectJ and Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, aspectj, load-time-weaving, perf4j

I tried to configure load-time weaving (for doing profiling with Perf4J) in the next way:

1) I added `aop.xml` to `META-INF` folder. When deployed, META-INF is placed in the artifact root directory (i.e. `MyAppDeployed/META-INF`).

2) I put `aspectjrt-1.6.1.jar`, `aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar`, `commons-jexl-1.1.jar`, `commons-logging.jar` to the `Tomcat/lib` folder (at first I tried `MyAppDeployed/WEB-INF/libs` but it also didn't work).

3) I added `-javaagent:C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\lib\aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar` to VM options when starting Tomcat.

4) My `aop.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">

<aspectj>

    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.perf4j.log4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">           
        <include within="com.mypackages.MyClass"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

I don't see any signs that load-time weaving happens. Neither error-reports nor necessary results. The only error message I have is:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\lib\wrong-jar.jar
```

in a case when I do a mistake in a `aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar` name when specify a javaagent parameter. If it's written correctly - no error messages are printed.

Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I use Java 5, and I tried the same things with `1.5.4` version of the aspectj with exactly the same results.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm trying to configure Aspectj + tomcat with load time weaving in Eclipse. Specifically I'm trying to weave JSP's but am having no luck.

Comment: I have a similar situation but have it working when the annotation is on my implementation class.Is your com.mypackages.MyClass an interface or implementation? My aspects were not getting weaved when I have the annotation on the interface. Also one more thing I have the aop.xml file under ../webapps/MyAppDeployed/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/aop.xml not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use load time weaving, you can first compile your classes with *javac* as usual then compile your aspect(s) with *(i)ajc*. You can do this with an ant task like below

```
<target name="compile-aspect">
    <iajc source="1.6" target="1.6" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true" outxml="true" debug="true" outjar="${dist.dir}/myaspect.jar">
            <argfiles>
                    <pathelement location="${src.dir}/sources.lst"/>
            </argfiles>
            <classpath>
                    <path refid="master-classpath" />
            </classpath>
    </iajc>
</target>
```

It is enough to have **aspectjrt.jar** in the classpath (*"master-classpath"*) during compilation.

Since all of my Java classes in *${src.dir}*, I give a source list to iajc. In source list there is only one line.

*sources.lst*

```
com/xx/yy/zz/LoggingAspect.java
```

I set some of iajc task's attributes as follows

```
outxml="true"
outjar="jar_file_name"
```

When I run compile-aspect task I have a jar **jar_file_name.jar** file contains

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/xx/yy/zz/LoggingAspect.class
META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
```

And finally add the *jar_file_name.jar* to your web application's **WEB-INF/lib** folder.

Then start Tomcat with **-javaagents:/path_to_aspectjweaver.jar** as you did before.

**When I put the aop.xml (or aop-ajc.xml) in META-INF under the war file directly it doesn't work.** This way (I mean seperating aspect classes into a jar) just works fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The point that I was missing and witch is obviously very important is the tag `outxml="true" ` when building. Without this, you don't have the `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml` that the aspectjweaver uses in order to know what are the _aspects_ to apply.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to solve the same issue in Tomcat. In addition to -javaagent option, you need to make sure the aop.xml must be under the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF dir. This made the difference for me.